# Вводное слово МОЖЕТ

Tags: пунктуация

Вот такое предложение: **Может даже им станет стыдно**.
Если выделить запятой вводное слово "может", получится, что акцент падает на "им": *Может, **даже им** станет стыдно*. Но мне надо акцентировать "может", заострить внимание на возможности того, что "им станет стыдно". Правомерно ли в этом случае поставить запятую после даже: **Может даже**, им станет стыдно**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, вполне можно. Ведь *даже* - усилительная частица, и ее ставят перед тем словом, на котором хотят акцентировать внимание.

Comment: Но у меня-то после.

Comment: НЕ придала значения слову "перед". Скажем, рядом со словом. Например, только этому я обязана или этому только я обязана.

Comment: Уверена, что запятую после "даже" в этом предложении ставить нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Если кроме НИХ (которым должно стыдно стать) больше никого не было, то запятую ставить можно там, где запланировали.

Answer (score 0):

```
Может даже им станет стыдно.
```

Запятой здесь не нужно. Вводное слово отделено от последующей части предложения частицей "даже". Поэтому запятая не ставится, а Вы достигаете желаемого результата: логическое ударение смещается именно на слово "может".

Comment: Без запятой получается  КАЗНИТЬ НЕЛЬЗЯ ПОМИЛОВАТЬ.