# Может(,) я могу что-то подсказать

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, нужна ли здесь запятая?

Comment: Кажется, повтор вопроса: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10683/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82

Comment: Был еще один вопрос на эту тему: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6759/%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%9c%d0%9e%d0%96%d0%95%d0%a2

Comment: И еще один: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416961/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8

Answer (score 2):

**может**
Вводное слово (в значении ***возможно, вероятно***; употребляется при выражении неуверенного подтверждения); сокращённая форма вводного слова ***может быть***.
В Вашем предложении выделяется запятой.

***Может,*** я могу что-то подсказать?
**Может быть,** я могу чем-то помочь?
**Может,** я могу решить твою проблему?

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Не поленитесь, посмотрите еще первые две ссылки, которые указал М_Г. Там есть интересные примеры,  рассматриваются некоторые особенности.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это вводное слово, запятая ставится.

Comment: Может я, может он, может и мы все проявляем излишнее усердие в расстановке запятых?